# Regular Expression accepting alphanumeric and /.~?=+&

Tags: php, regex, special-characters

I need a validation expression that accepts alphanumeric characters and these special characters /.~?=+&

I'm doing this in php so it either gives me errors or not working at all

I tried this thing. But it don't accept even alphanumerics:

```
preg_match('/^[\w ]+([\.\~\?\=\+\&][\w ]*)?$/',$var)
```

Comment: What are you testing it against? How are you performing that test? What errors do you get? What does "not working at all" mean?

Comment: I'm entering data into a form and then try to validate it with regex. Different errors about delimiters and stuff but basically because I'dont know regex very well. "Not working at all" means that it either pass it though if it incorrect or don't even if it is true

Comment: Like so? http://regex101.com/r/yA5oW8

Comment: can your string have two consecutive special characters? can your string begin or end with a special character? are spaces allowed? are underscores allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to escape characters within `[]`. The only ones that have to be escaped are `\`,`/`,`[` and `[`. To match alphanumeric and your set of special characters try following:

```
(\w|[\/.~?=+&])*
```

Comment: And the slash... `\/`

Comment: Oh, I missed that one. Thank you @scrowler!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\/?&+~=.]*$/i', $var, $match);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can represent alphanumeric and the above characters using the following expression:

`[[:alnum:]\/.~?=+&]`

You could then use this PHP code to iterate over all matches in a string...

```
preg_match_all('%[[:alnum:]/.~?=+&]*%i', $var, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    # Matched text = $result[0][$i];
}
```